# Show my GWT textarea Widget in two diffrent HTML pages

Tags: html, google-app-engine, jsp, gwt

I'm wondering if it is possible to show my GWT textarea widget in two diffrent HTML pages?
As when i try it doesn't work..
Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the failing code?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the same instance of a widget in two places at once.  You can use two instances of the same widget in different places however you like.

Won't work:

```
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
panel1.add(textArea);
panel2.add(textArea);
```

Will work:

```
TextArea textArea1 = new TextArea();
TextArea textArea51 = new TextArea();
panel1.add(textArea1);
panel2.add(textArea51);
```

Comment: Man....when i try it works fine but I use those textareas to put there contents in an array list and send them to the server,the server insert them in the JDO datastore, that works fine when i use ONE GWT textarea widget but when i add more Textareas that do the same functionality nothing of them works even the one that work when it was alone:( can you help finding the problem???